# Is there any "Virtual LDAP" gateway?

Tags: mysql, authentication, ldap, openldap

I use LDAP server only for user authentication in redmine, nginx, grafana, etc.
Can you suggest any "virtual ldap" gateway (some utility which can handle queries as LDAP server)? I want to store user info in MySQL db. No groups needed or advanced LDAP features needed, only user authentication.

Comment: Is http://www.wingfoss.com/content/how-to-install-openldap-with-mysql-on-debian6 any use?

Comment: There is the SQL backend for OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution myself: http://myvd.sourceforge.net/

This tool can be used as "LDAP-gateway" to any storage or system on backend side.